# Why is the Stack Overflow 10m page still up?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Why is the Stack Overflow 10 million question page still up and accessible? We hit 10m on August 20 last year (2015), and now it's January 2016. Is it still there because someone didn't take it down?

[Link to 10m page](https://stackoverflow.com/10m)

Comment: Did you notice the counters are still updating?

Comment: @πάντα yes I noticed that

Comment: But the T shirt offer has expired, right? The phrase "the next four weeks" is obsolete by now.

Comment: @jongware yes, that offer was long gone...

Comment: Well, why not? What harm is it causing? It's the same as Winter Bash that they leave up long time after it's over.

Comment: I could imagine it still being visible since the rewards haven't been sent out yet C:

Comment: It's down now. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 12):

Because, why not? If it's bothering it so much that there're more than 10m questions already, imagine it's not about 10m. It's not obsolete, and you can find some interesting stats and facts there.

Comment: Part of it *is* obsolete. `Whether you've been giving for years or are just getting started, we'd be honored to help you geek out. Each of the next four weeks, we'll randomly award 50 men's and 50 women's tees to helpers just like you. Just show off that you're here to help, and we'll enter you in that week's drawing.

#SOreadytohelp`

Comment: @Martin Hm, that's fair. Though nothing else appears to be obsolete?..

Comment: I'm not sure if the 7,522,902,979 figure is static too? Doesn't seem to be changing.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't really need to be taken down, but if it's left for the public to see, it should be maintained.  From the looks of it, that has not been the case.