# What happened to the 10 million questions page? It now puts up a 404

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

https://stackoverflow.com/10m now gives a 404 when before it showed all the cool stats about Stack Overflow! Does anyone know what happened to it?

Comment: It was likely removed since now we're well past that milestone.

Comment: [Why is the Stack Overflow 10m page still up?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314894/why-is-the-stack-overflow-10m-page-still-up)

Comment: We're going to reach another milestone.

Comment: Oh man, I never saw this page, now I want to. I hope it comes back `:D`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Then get busy on that delete queue!

Comment: Thanks to `Disallow: /10m` on [robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt), [wayback machine couldn't archive it](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.com/10m).

Comment: Here is the site archived: http://archive.is/https://stackoverflow.com/10m (archive.is does not follow robots.txt it seems, thank god for that...)

Comment: @RAnders00 It seems it only crawls from direct user input. Thank you whoever did that!